# Fully disabling dedicated graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics, asus-laptop

I am planning to buy a ASUS K555LN laptop with i3-5010 and Nvidia geforce 840m GC. I want to know if there will be option to fully disable Nvidia Graphic Card and switch to Intel integrated and also option to fully disable Intel integrated and switch to Nvidia dedicated graphic card. I have some questions about that:

- Will Nvidia Graphic card be consuming power/generating heat after disabling it?
- Will disabling Nvidia Graphic Card driver in Device Manager fully disable it?
- I hear something about Nvidia Optimus technology. Is this technology applicable to this laptop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will Nvidia graphics card be consuming power/generating heat after disabling it?

No

> Will disabling the Nvidia graphics card driver in  the Windows Device Manager fully disable it?

Yes

You can also override the default graphics processor for a program. You can activate a setting in the NVIDIA Control Panel that allows you to override the Optimus application profile setting and choose a particular graphics processor to use. To enable this setting, click *View* from the NVIDIA Control Panel menu bar and select *Add "Run with graphics processor" Option to Context Menu*. This setting will now allow you to right-click on any executable or shortcut and select the graphics processor to be used when running the application, either High-performance NVIDIA processor or Integrated graphics.<sup>**1**</sup>

> I've heard something about Nvidia Optimus technology. Is this technology applicable to this laptop?

Nvidia Optimus technology intelligently optimizes your laptop, providing the better graphics performance you need, when you need it, while extending battery life.

According to the [official GeForce website](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus/supported-gpus) the GeForce 840M GPU supports the Nvidia Optimus GPU switching technology. For laptops with GPUs that support Nvidia Optimus, Intel Core i3, i5 and i7 processors are supported.

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>[How do I customize Optimus profiles and settings?](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2615/~/how-do-i-customize-optimus-profiles-and-settings%3F)</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28870/discussion-on-answer-by-karel-fully-disabling-dedicated-graphic-card).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

- in BIOS, change `Primary Graphics Adaptor` from `PCI` to `Onboard`
- move hdmi cord to motherboard
- in powershell run `Get-CimInstance win32_VideoController`. I saw my `Nvidia` and `microsoft basic render driver` the software renderer.
- update windows. It should download the `intel driver`
- `microsoft basic render driver` should disappear from powershell's `Get-CimInstance win32_VideoController`.
- in task manager I now see both `Intel` and `Nvidia`.
- go to device manager and disable the `Nvidia` driver.
- `Nvidia` should disappear from task manager.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable nvidia driver but you can't disable the intel driver. Intel gpu will always be active. You wont even be able to install the nvidia driver without installing the intel driver.

Comment: "but you can't disable the intel driver" It is not true. You can disable Intel graphics, Atleat from a windows10 device.

Comment: Desktop or laptop

Comment: For both Laptop(ASUS ROG series) and Desktop(HP work station series).